# Клик на clusterCaption в балуне кластера Яндекс-карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

На карте вывожу метки. Если по одному адресу 2 и более метки, тогда метки собираются в кластер.
При клике на метку я отслеживаю событие

myPlacemark.events.add('click', function (e) {...});

Некоторые метки расположены в одной координате, поэтому при клике на кластер они не раскрываются, а открывается балун со списком clusterCaption.

Как отследить событие клика на этот clusterCaption в балуне?

Comment: добавьте сниппет с примером карты добавления и кластериазации. событие `hintopen` кластера это не то, что вам надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом (может кому пригодится):

```
            // определяю событие клика на кластере
            clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
                // получаем ссылку на объект, по которому кликнули
                var cluster = e.get('target');//.state.get('activeObject')
                    // включаем монитор слежения по переключению clusterCaption в балуне кластера
                    var stateMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(cluster.state);
                    stateMonitor.add('activeObject', function(activeObject) {
                        // любые действия по выбранной метке кластера
                    });

            });
```